# Get bitbake to use a different locale

Tags: locale, yocto, bitbake

I'm running through the Yocto Quick Build tutorial, and I've got to the command

```bash
bitbake core-image-sato
```

This is producing the error

> Your system need to support the en_US.UTF-8 locale.

Can I change this so it uses the en_GB.UTF-8 locale? I don't want to end up with a build that uses a US locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know from the top of my head why it expects your system to support `en_US.UTF-8`, but my guess is that some recipe or tool needs to parse another program's output, which hence needs to be localized the "right" way.

Set up the `en_US.UTF-8` locale and finish building. Note that it says **support**, not "be set to".

Comment: Thanks. I added the en_US locale, and it worked.